# java - sql results are not displaying in the jTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I'm new to java. I'm following a tutorial to retrieve images and other data from db to a jTable. I have 4 columns in the db. This was supposed to display the available data in the db to jTable. But nothing is happening. Not even a error is showing. I have added all my code. Any help would be appreciated !

Course.java

```
package my.welcomescreen;


public class Course {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private byte[] imag;
    private String desc;

public Course(){}

public Course(int Id, String Name, byte[] image, String description){
    this.id = Id;
    this.name = Name;
    this.imag = image;
    this.desc = description;
}

public int getID(){
    return id;
}

public void setID(int ID){
    this.id = ID;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setName(String Name){
    this.name = Name;
}

public byte[] getImage(){
    return imag;
}

public String getDesc(){
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String Description){
    this.desc = Description;
}
}
```

MainQuery.java

```
package my.welcomescreen;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MainQuery {

    public ArrayList<Course> BindTable(){
    ArrayList<Course> list = new ArrayList<Course>();
    db databaseCon = new db();
    Connection dbconnect = db.dbconnect();
    Connection con = databaseCon.dbconnect();
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    try{
        st = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "select id,name,img,description from courses";
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        Course c;
        while(rs.next()){
            c = new Course(
                            rs.getInt("id"),
                            rs.getString("name"),
                            rs.getBytes("img"),
                            rs.getString("description")
                           );

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Admin_Panel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return list;

   }


}
```

TheModel.java

```
package my.welcomescreen;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;


public class TheModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] columns;
    private Object[][] rows;

    public TheModel(){}

    public TheModel(Object[][] data, String[] columnName){
        this.rows = data;
        this.columns = columnName;
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int Column){
        if(Column == 2){
            return Icon.class;
        } else {
            return getValueAt(0,Column).getClass();
        }
    }


    public int getRowCount() {
        return this.rows.length;
    }


    public int getColumnCount() {
        return this.columns.length;
    }


public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
     return this.rows[rowIndex][columnIndex]; 
}

public String getColumnName(int col){
    return this.columns[col];
}

}
```

Main Method

```
public void displayJTable(){
    MainQuery mq = new MainQuery();
    ArrayList<Course> list = mq.BindTable();
    String[] columnName = {"Id","Course Name","Image","Description"};
    Object[][] rows = new Object[list.size()][3];
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        rows[i][0] = list.get(i).getID();
        rows[i][1] = list.get(i).getName();

        if(list.get(i).getImage() != null){

         ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(list.get(i).getImage()).getImage()
         .getScaledInstance(150, 120, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH) );   

        rows[i][2] = image;
        }

        rows[i][3] = list.get(i).getDesc();
    }

    TheModel model = new TheModel(rows, columnName);
    jTable1.setModel(model);
    jTable1.setRowHeight(120);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(150);


}
```

Comment: (1-) Why are you creating a custom `Course` Object to hold the data and then copy the Course data to a 2D Array? Why are you creating a custom TableModel that simply holds the data in a 2D Array.There is  new reason to do this. Just use the DefaultTableModel. You can read the data from the ResultSet directly into the DefaultTableModel. If you are going to take the time to create a custom `Course` object and read the data into the Object, then create a proper TableModel that supports the `Course` Object. You where given the solution in your last question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see you adding every course to the list in the below snippet:

```
 Course c;
    while(rs.next()){
        c = new Course(
                        rs.getInt("id"),
                        rs.getString("name"),
                        rs.getBytes("img"),
                        rs.getString("description")
                       );
      // this line below should be added
      list.add(c)
    }
```